# Action creators doc comments not showing

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Looking at adopting using redux-toolkit in our app but I can't seem to get the doc comments we have for our action creators to show.

Old code:

```
const ADD_NAME = 'ADD_NAME';
/**
 * Sets the name for the user in our state.
 * @param name The updated name
 */
export function addName(name: string) {
   return {
     payload: name,
     type: ADD_NAME,
   };
}
```

In VSCode, whenever I dispatch `addName()`, hovering over the function gives me the tooltip with the documentation there as expected.

Recreating this action creator using redux-toolkit:

```
/**
 * Sets the name for the user in our state.
 * @param name The updated name of the User
 */
export const addName = createAction<string>(ADD_NAME);
```

When I hover over this new `addName` during a dispatch, instead of seeing the documentation I wrote:

`Sets the name for the user in our state.`

I see this:

`Calling this {@link redux#ActionCreator} with an argument will return a {@link PayloadAction} of type T with a payload of P`

That's the internal documentation for `ActionCreatorWithPayload` from the redux-toolkit typings file.

What am I missing that the doc comments I added for my `addName` action creator is shown and not the redux-toolkit doc comments?

I realize one is me commenting a function and the other is commenting a const var, but I'd have expected my comments for that `addName` const to be shown as the tooltip, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very good question. This seems to depend on the editor - and on the context in which the documentation is accessed.

In VSCode, it looks like this at first: [image: Screenshot from VSCode]

When you just write `addName`, until it is completed, you get the docblock from the variable `addName`. Once you write a `(`, it looks "into" the variable value, recognizes the function and takes the docblock from the function itself - and that is an action creator.

I do not think that you can really override that behavior any further, but I'd love to see someone to come up with a good way.

---

I did some more experimenting: while TypeScript does lose most comments on mapped function types, you could use one object argument instead of positional arguments and annotate the individual properties with docblocks. That would probably give you the most info that is possible given what TypeScript offers at the moment (and of course, autocomplete for the "argument names"):

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    test: {
      prepare({name, age}: {
        /** The name! */
        name: string,
        /** The age! */
        age: number
      }
      ) {
        return { payload: { name, age } };
      },
      reducer(x, action: any) { }
    }
  }
})

// hovering over age or name will give you more info
slice.actions.test({ age: 5, name: "" })
```

Comment: It sure makes for a less intuitive dev experience. We have a bunch of action creators that take multiple params. Having the docs right there in the tooltip as you are calling the dispatch explaining each param and its purpose is really huge.
  
I know you can use those "Prepare" functions in RTK to handle action creators with multiple params, and we'd have to move the documentation to that helper function most likely.  But still, it makes our codebase less intuitive to use -- even if it is cleaner/less boilerplate in the end.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunately pretty much how TSServer works - there is not too much to be done there I fear

Comment: Added one option to pass through at least a bit of info.

Comment: Yeah I think the prepare function way might be the best alternative, even though it's still more typing. Super frustrating! Thanks for taking a wack at it though.

Comment: I mean, I used the prepare function in the example here, but I think you can just type the payload of a `PayloadAction` exactly the same way.

Comment: Yeah we have typed payloads in other action creators. But if the payload is a string, the bigger issue is missing the doc comment explaining the context of what exactly this string should be. It's less a problem about what props/types we need passed in. More so about "what is this string I'm passing in used for?"

Comment: You can always pass in an object with only one string property. Not really perfect, but we can't really do anything here on the library level.